# Want to disable CSRF in openedx for one specific post request

Tags: python, django, openedx

In openedx I have used Xblock.json_handler for third party api consumption . But I want to disable csrf authentication for that one post api , can anyone help me out with that ?

Answer (score 0):

They are many ways to do just that. But just have in mind that you cannot disable CSRF at global level unless you will
like to create your own custom middleware.
see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#contrib-and-reusable-apps)

**1.) using csrf_exempt method**

If you want some views not to use CSRF, you can use **@csrf_exempt**.
Add **@csrf_exempt** to every view that you want to disable

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return 'CSRF is disabled for this view'
```

**2.) Using setting.py configurations**

In setting.py in MIDDLEWARE you can simply remove/comment this line of code:

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

Just remember that SessionAuthentication performs its own CSRF validation. and this will trigger CSRF missing error 
if commented while using sessionAuthentication..

```
3.) Creating your own Custom Middleware
```

To disable CSRF in Global, you can write a custom middleware, like this

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class DisableCsrfCheck(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, req):
        attr = '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks'
        if not getattr(req, attr, False):
            setattr(req, attr, True)
```

then add this class

`yourApp_name.middlewarefilename.DisableCsrfCheck`

to

`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES lists`,

before

```
 django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware
```